# Python Regex to parse apart Blackberry browser user agent

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse apart blackberry browser user agents so I can get what device and version it is using python 2.5. For example:

```
BlackBerry9630/4.7.1.65 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/-1,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)
```

In the above user agent I would like to gather the following groups:

> ```
> Browser: Blackberry 
> Device: 9630 
> Major Version: 4 
> Minor Version: 7
> ```

The rest of the info I don't care about.

Here is another example:

```
BlackBerry9530/5.0.0.328 Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/105,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)
```

> ```
> Browser: Blackberry
> Device: 9530
> Major Version: 5
> Minor Version: 0
> ```

I'm horrible at figuring out regex and any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work for your case, but not necessarily all cases:

```
'^(\D*)(\d*)/(\d*)\.(\d*)\.'
```

`\D` means "any character that's not a decimal digit", and `\d` means "any decimal digit".

Answer (score 0):

```
browser, version = useragent.split()[0].split("/")
browsername = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]+", browser)
device = re.findall(r"[0-9]+", browser)
versions = re.findall(r"[0-9]+", version)
major = versions[0]
minor = versions[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'BlackBerry9530/5.0.0.328 Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/105,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)'
>>> print(re.compile(r'(Blackberry)(\d+)/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.',re.I).search(s).groups())
('BlackBerry', '9530', '5', '0')
>>>
```